# Is this hadith about dhikr authentic?

Tags: hadith, authenticity

> Aasim bin Bahdah, from Abee Saalih from Umm Haanee bint Abee Taalib
>   (Prophet’s cousin). She said,"The Messenger of Allaah passed by me so
>   I said, ‘I have become old and weak (or she said somethingsimilar) so
>   order me with something I can do whilst sitting.’ He said, ‘Say
>   ‘subhaan Allaah’ one hundred times, it will be equal to freeing 100
>   slaves f rom the offspring of Ismaa’eel.Say ‘alhamdulillaah’ one
>   hundred times, it will be equal to giving 100 horses equipped with
>   lights and bridles ready to fight for the sake of Allaah in charity.
>   Say ‘ Allaahu akbar’ one hundred times, it will be equal to 100
>   garlanded sacrifices. Say ‘laa ilaaha illAllaah’ one hundred times,
>   (ibn Khalf, the narrator from Aasim, said I think he said) it fills
>   what is between the heavens and the earth. And nobody comes on that
>   day with anything better except that he does the same as you have
>   done."

IS IT AUTHENTIC ?